# File reading not working in Brython/Python

Tags: python, brython

My requirement: Read contents from a input type="file" with ID= "rtfile1" and write it to a textarea with ID- "rt1"

Based on the documentation on [https://brython.info/][1] I tried to read a file but it fails with this error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/fakepath/requirements.txt' from origin 'http://example.com:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

I tried following two Brython codes, both of them failed with the same aforementioned error.

Code 1:

```
def file_read(ev):
    doc['rt1'].value = open(doc['rtfile1'].value).read()
doc["rtfile1"].bind("input", file_read)
```

Code 2:

```
 def file_read(ev):
    def on_complete(req):
        if req.status==200 or req.status==0:
            doc['rt1'].value = req.text
        else:
            doc['rt1'].value = "error "+req.text

    def err_msg():
        doc['rt1'].value = "server didn't reply after %s seconds" %timeout

    timeout = 4

    def go(url):
        req = ajax.ajax()
        req.bind("complete", on_complete)
        req.set_timeout(timeout, err_msg)

        req.open('GET', url, True)

        req.send()
    print('Triggered')
    go(doc['rtfile1'].value)

doc["rtfile1"].bind("input", file_read)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!! :)

Answer (score 3):

It's not related to Brython (you would have the same result with the equivalent Javascript), but to the way you tell the browser which file you want to upload.

If you select the file by an HTML tag such as

```html
<input type="file" id="rtfile1">
```

the object referenced by `doc['rtfile1']` in the Brython code has an attribute `value`, but it is *not* the file path or url, it's a "fakepath" built by the browser (as you can see in the error message), and you can't use it as an argument of the Brython function `open()`, or as a url to send an Ajax request to; if you want to use the file url, you should enter it in a basic input tag (without `type="file"`).

It *is* better to select the file with `type="file"`, but in this case the object `doc['rtfile1']` is a FileList object, described in the [DOM's Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList), whose first element is a File object. Reading its content is unfortunately not as simple as with `open()`, but here is a working example:

```python
from browser import window, document as doc

def file_read(ev):

    def onload(event):
        """Triggered when file is read. The FileReader instance is
        event.target.
        The file content, as text, is the FileReader instance's "result"
        attribute."""
        doc['rt1'].value = event.target.result

    # Get the selected file as a DOM File object
    file = doc['rtfile1'].files[0]
    # Create a new DOM FileReader instance
    reader = window.FileReader.new()
    # Read the file content as text
    reader.readAsText(file)
    reader.bind("load", onload)

doc["rtfile1"].bind("input", file_read)
```